# CSS Psuedo ::after is not applied in Firefox updated 63

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

Last night my Firefox just got updated to version 63 without notice, the image in my website that used to be displayed correctly just got broken.

The image that I put on the web, I used css content class

```
 /*Chrome*/
.pswFilled{
    content:url("psw_filled.png");
}

/*Firefox*/
.pswFilled::after{
    content:url("psw_filled.png");
}
```

Before updated, this worked correctly. If chrome is detected, the non-pseudo is applied. Also Firefox uses the pseudo one. However after updated, if both are put like this, Firefox will pick the non-pseudo to use first and vanish the image.

If I remove the non-pseudo line, Firefox picks the pseudo one and the image will display correctly but disappear in chrome.

Anyone experienced this? Please help

Comment: Eesh. Nothing in the Fx 63 release notes says anything about elements now supporting the content property. Now I'm *really* curious. Having said that, you're gonna have to provide the markup needed to reproduce this problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/extempl/zsyfj5eg/ works in both Chrome and Firefox 63. If remove the non-pseudo one it still will work in both browsers.

Comment: Somehow I have the feeling this is not an ordinary div or something. Is it an input?

Comment: Thanks guys. I found the solution and put the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all those trying to help. I found the problem and already solved.

The problem happened because I put the class into the img element

I thought it should work same way to the div tag. Actually it used to be working before the firefox update to 63.

Before, I wrote this way.

```
<img id='pwdBox' class='pswFilled'/>
```

It worked in both Chrome and Firefox (before 63)

but in 63, I have to change it to  this

```
<div id='pwdBox' class='pswFilled'></div>
```

Thanks to extempl whose enlightened me with jsfiddle